# perfect forwarding confusion

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

Hello everyone,

```
template<typename X>
int mycall(const X& a)
{
    std::cout << ">>>  " << "int mycall(const X& a)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template<typename X>
int mycall(X&& a)
{
    std::cout << ">>>  " << "int mycall(X&& a)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}



template <typename T>
class CClass
{
public:

    CClass(T t) : m_t{t}
    {
    }

    template<typename U>
    auto operator()(U&& t)
    {
        mycall(std::forward<U>(t));
    }


private:

    T m_t;
};



class A{};

int main()
{

    CClass cc{5};

    //1..
    int x = 9;    
    cc(x);
    
    cc(10);
    cc(A{});

    //4..
    A a{};
    cc(a);

    return 0;
}

output:

>>>  int mycall(X&& a)
>>>  int mycall(X&& a)
>>>  int mycall(X&& a)
>>>  int mycall(X&& a)
```

In the example above, for the **first** and **fourth** calls, I initially expected that the universal reference would deduce as an lvalue reference, leading to the *mycall(const T&)* version being called due to perfect forwarding. However, I observed that the *mycall(T&&)* version is called instead.

When I removed the const qualifier, changing the function to *mycall(T&)*, the first and fourth calls are forwarded as lvalue references, and as a result, the *mycall(T&)* version is called as expected. What is the effect of the const qualifier here? Why is the argument forwarded as an rvalue reference?

Comment: `int mycall(X&& a)` is **also** using a universal reference.  That's why it is favored over the `const` version.  It's an exact match.

Comment: `template<typename X> int mycall(X&& a)` - this is not an overload for only r-value references, as you said this is a perfect forwarding, `X` is deduced as `int` and `A` in the cases 2-3, and as `const int&` and `const A&` in the cases 1 and 4, then the parameter type `const T&&&` is reduced to `const T&`. If you had done `template<typename X> int mycall(const X& a)` to be a regular function `int mycall(const X& a)`, then it would be a preferred choice while the lookup.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, `int mycall(X&& a)` is also using a forwarding reference, hence it is prefered over the other template.

Forwarding requires the template argument to be deduced, so one way to get the desired output is to not let it be deduced again:

```
template<typename U>
auto operator()(U&& t)
{
    mycall<U>(std::forward<U>(t));
}
```

[Resulting output](https://godbolt.org/z/nY7ooK5r9):

```
>>>  int mycall(const X& a)
>>>  int mycall(X&& a)
>>>  int mycall(X&& a)
>>>  int mycall(const X& a)
```